How to set p and q values in Node2Vec for sparse user-item interactions with rich user and item attributes?
I am using Node2Vec for recommendation tasks, but my dataset has sparse user-item interactions. Many users are cold-start users, and most users have few interactions with items (user-item relationships). However, each user has additional attributes such as institution ID, institution type, gender, and preferences, and each item has detailed attributes like tags and authorship information.
How should I set the p and q parameters in Node2Vec to:
Leverage the few existing user-item relationships effectively?
Utilize user and item attributes (like institution ID, institution type for users, and tags, authorship for items) to mitigate the cold-start problem?
Should I assign different weights to different types of edges, such as user preference edges or gender edges, to emphasize certain relationships? If so, how should this be done?
I know that the amplified p will increase the probability of BFS, thus walking near the actual node, so that the distance is close, especially the embedding results between directly connected nodes are close, and the amplified q will increase the probability of DFS, but I don’t know for In my scenario, how should I control the wandering to better solve the cold start problem for me.
